# c# - How to cut triangle from image?

Tags: c#, drawing, border

I use C# in my work.
I want to render a border with different weigths on its sides.
Like this:

[image]

[image]

This pictures are from browser, I want to draw corners the same way.
May be the best and the simplest way to implement it is to cut corners from borders at specified angle,  like this:

[image]

but I have no idea how to cut triangles from image using c# drawing API, and, unfortunately, google doesn't help with this task, there is information only about cropping rectangles.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to render the triangles on to? A web page? A Windows form? A piece of paper?

Comment: @Derek Tomes, a piece of Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GraphicsPath for this. Define a path of a number of points (a shape) and perform garphics operations on it just like it was a rectanble.

Comment: Yes, but what it will give for me? How may it help to render different borders on different sides? Unfortunately, as far as I know, GraphicsPath cannot do this.

Comment: You could 'draw' the Path/Shape around whatever you want to paint or cut out. I suggest you draw trapezoids instead of lines. This can be done using GraphicsPath.

Comment: You mean, extract GraphicsPath from image? If yes, its quite interesting suggestion. Gonna think about it, thanks.